# How do i resolve this error when requesting JSON from Flask back end?: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, python-3.x, flask-restful

Im currently creating an app that uses python to send a dictionary to my React front end using Flask. Even though I'm returnng valid JSON from my back end, my front end also shows this error:

JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Any help would be much appreciated!

This is the server.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/members")
def members():
    return {"members": ["Member1","Member2","Member3"]}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

This is the App.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([{}])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/members").then(
      res => res.json()
    ).then(
      data => {
        setData(data)
        console.log(data)
      }
    )
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

This is the index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

---

Upon running the code, this ALWAYS gives the following error:

Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR
JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
ERROR
JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Use the browser "Network" tool to see what is actually being returned to the browser. It's probably some sort of error formatted as HTML, but by being able to look at it you'll get a better idea of what the actual error is.

Comment: OK! I did this and somehow im getting the entire index.html document of my react app. How is this happening?

Comment: well maybe the routing via that path ("/members") isn't working for some reason

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown when the data I'd not in JSON format.

Check if the data actually is being returned in the expected format.

You can also ensure that the returned data is in a valid JSON format with something like this:

```
@app.route("/members")
def members():
    return jsonify({"members": ["Member1", "Member2", "Member3"]})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Greg, Ive made the changes to my server.py and am getting the same error.

Comment: What's the response from `/members` when called directly? The error means that the response is not in json format, so parse will fail. Try to console.log res.text() at the point where you have res.json(). You can check the network tab in DevTools and look for /members as well